# SM-G525F (Samsung Galaxy XCover 5) - How to activate Flash and Torch LED at the same time

Tags: android, xamarin, led, samsung

The SM-G525F (Samsung Galaxy XCover 5) has two build in flashlights on its backside. One is the torch which is available by the android menu and the other one is the camera flash.

I can activate the camera flash when using xamarin.essentials. However there seems to be no way to activate the torch LED when the camera flash LED is activated.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you sure they're not the same LED?  On many models they are.  In fact the flashlight feature originally was just a hack keeping the flash on for a protracted exposure, it wasn't originally meant as a feature.

Comment: No they are seperate LEDs. If I turn on the flash when in camera the upper one is activated, when I turn on the flashlight via android quick menu the lower one is activated. I've tried to activate them both in an example app but get following error message: `Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraAccessException: 'CAMERA_IN_USE (4): setTorchMode:2330: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user'` - I've used xamarin essentials flashlight for the lower LED and zxing.isTorchon for the upper LED in this quick test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just took a look at the [product description](https://www.galaxyxcover5.com/) and according to Samsung both LEDs won't turn on simultaneusly.

Comment: Should I delete this question because it's useless?

Comment: It's not useless.  Knowing something can't be done is as useful as knowing how to do it if it can.